# what change is needed to make my Haskell code to take more generic pattern?

Tags: haskell

Here is my coding in Haskell:

```
(Add (Y 0 3) (Add (Y 1 1) (Y 2 1))) (Add (Y 0 3) (Add (Y 1 1) (Y 2 1)))
```

How do I make my code more generic pattern from the input so it is not as restricted as per my coding?

Comment: What is the definition of Poli and X?

Comment: Y is Y, there is no value for Y, like the input is (Y 0 1) where 0 is the exponent, 1 is the coefficient

Comment: oh I realized I have a typo "data Poly" should be written as "data Poli"

Comment: oh I realized I have a typo "data Poly" should be written as "data Poli" and "X" is actually "Y"

Comment: @Yorkman can't you edit your own question and correct those typos?

Comment: @Yorkman Okay, I see, it may clear for other readers by correct the typo of your question. Otherwise, just a suggestion, see the answer as below, simplify the design using list instead of recursive type

Comment: How exactly is it not working? What is the actual result? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Yorkman now after this edit, it's outright impossible to see what you're asking.

Comment: You have removed all content from the question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

There may not has a standard answer for design question. Just a suggestion, I suspect   whether is suitable to define `data Poli` as a recursive type.

In mathematics, polynomial just a summation of terms, so, we may define polynomial as

```
data PolyTerm = X Exponent Coefficient deriving Show
data Poli = Term PolyTerm | Add [PolyTerm] deriving Show
```

and the product of two terms just as before:

```
termMultiple ::PolyTerm -> PolyTerm -> PolyTerm
termMultiple (X e1 c1) (X e2 c2) = (X (e1+e2) (c1*c2)
```

and the product of two polynomial can be as a list comprehension:

```
poliMultiple :: Poli -> Poli -> Poli
poliMultiple (Add ps1) (Add ps2)  = 
        Add [ termMultiple t1 t2 | t1 <- ps1, t2 <- ps2]
```

and the other 3 cases can be wrapped

```
poliMultiple (Term t1) (Term t2) = Term (termMultiple t1 t2)
poliMultiple (Term p1) ps2@(Add ps) = poliMultiple (Add [p1]) ps2
poliMultiple ps1@(Add ps) (Term p2) = poliMultiple ps1 (Add [p2])
```

EDIT:
As the data type of Poli cannot be modified, the Poli may need to be flatten and reconstruct to the deserved output pattern as:
Add (X e c (Add (X e c) ... Add (X e c) (X e c)))..)

```
flatten::Poli->[Poli]
flatten t@(Y _ _) = [t]
flatten (Add t@(Y _ _) p) = [t] ++ flatten p
flatten (Add p t@(Y _ _)) = flatten p ++ [t]
flatten (Add p1 p2) = flatten p1 ++ flatten p2

construct::[Poli]->Poli
construct [t]  = t
construct (t:ts) = Add t (construct ts)
```

and the poliMultiple as

```
poliMultiple (Add p1 p2) (Add p3 p4) = 
    simplify $
        Add (poliMultiple p1 p3) 
            (Add (poliMultiple p1 p4) 
                (Add (poliMultiple p2 p3) (poliMultiple p2 p4)))
    where simplify = construct . flatten
```

The usage of (++) above is a most inefficient way, use stack or view Poli data type as a binary tree to traverse and construct it may be better.

Comment: Thanks that's a great idea in your solution and I agree with your comment that whether this custom data type Poli is suitable for recursive type. Having said that, unfortunately, I have been given with this custom data type to begin with so I need to keep on thinking how to make it work if there is a way. Hope later you can figure out or someone will step in to give me an advice / solution.

Comment: However, besides the typos, your original coding seems work with pattern: (Add (Y 0 3) (Add (Y 1 1) (Y 2 1))) (Add (Y 0 3) (Add (Y 1 1) (Y 2 1))). It gives the answer as: Add (Y 0 9) (Add (Add (Y 1 3) (Y 2 3)) (Add (Add (Y 1 3) (Y 2 3)) (Add (Y 2 1) (Add (Y 3 1) (Add (Y 3 1) (Y 4 1)))))), when I try it in GHCI

Comment: Yeah it looks like working but if u take a closer look , there is a “ Add ( Add (Y 1 3) ....” which I should not have “Add” alone without following (Y ...)

Comment: Since the Poli data type at most have two terms, how does you want to express a polynomial has 9 terms with it? Does It should be: Add ((Y..) (Add (Y..) Add (Y..) ..., The left value of Poli data type must be (Y...)?

Comment: may be I provide the proper output then it will explain what I mean...so to my output above, as said although it looks correct, the problem is with the "Add" did not bracket properly. So the output should be like Add (X 0 9) (Add (X 1 3) (Add (X 2 3) (Add (X 1 3) (Add (X 2 3) (Add (X 2 1) (Add (X 3 1) (Add (X 3 1) (X 4 1))))))))                                                                                             here is simple one that my coding works: Input : (Add (X 0 3) (X 2 1)) (Add (X 1 1) (X 2 1)) Output: Add (X 1 3) (Add (X 2 3) (Add (X 3 1) (X 4 1)))

Comment: That is mean that the left value of Add always be (X e c)? just said as forth comment, the output should be the pattern as:  Add (X e c) (Add (X e c) (Add (X e c) ...(Add (X..) (X..)))..),. Right?

Comment: If the data type of Poli cannot be modified, the simpler but not efficient way to do that is flatten the Poli to list of (X c e) and reconstruct as deserved output as your want.

Comment: yeah I agree with you and thanks for all your help, appreciate that.

Comment: As a example, see the EDIT of my answer, there is a quite easy but not efficient way to do that.

Comment: thanks so much, will take a closer look to your latest solution.